# How to read files from a directory having name "/" in S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark

Code:
val df = spark.read.csv("s3a://sample_bucket//csvFiles/file.csv");

Error:
22/06/23 20:02:57 WARN impl.MetricsConfig: Cannot locate configuration: tried hadoop-metrics2-s3a-file-system.properties,hadoop-metrics2.properties
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: s3a://sample_bucket//csvFiles/file.csv;
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:557)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:544)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:544)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:358)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:615)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:467)
... 49 elided

When I used the above code, got this error. The file path is taken from the UI directly, and I don't know why it is showing path does not exist error.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `Code: val df = spark.read.csv("s3a://sample_bucket/csvFiles/file.csv);`, without the double-slash?

Comment: Sorry, that's a mistake

Comment: Is it possible to create a folder without a name?

Comment: S3 doesn't actually have folders. You can create a zero-byte object at `/folder/`, and the S3 console will **pretend** it's a folder, but it isn't really one.

Comment: Can you help me out with the above error?